# Why does MySQL show Unknown column for a column that is clearly defined?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building a SQL query to produce a table of tickets which were accepted or closed late.

```
SELECT 
    svc_guid,
    svc_priority,
    cast(svc_minsinqueue AS SIGNED)-(pri_svc_accept_hours * 60) AS accept_overdue,
    cast(svc_minselapsed AS SIGNED)-(pri_svc_close_hours * 60) AS closure_overdue
FROM
    svcrequest
LEFT JOIN 
    priorities
ON 
    pri_id=svc_priority
WHERE
    accept_overdue > 0 OR
    closure_overdue > 0
ORDER BY 
    accept_overdue DESC;
```

The result is:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'accept_overdue' in 'where clause'
```

The same exact query with WHERE 1 will produce no errors. (Even with ORDER BY accept_overdue DESC)

Comment: It isn't a column. You have to repeat your "cast" in the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand SQL order of operation, you will understand why your code won't work.

```
FROM, including JOINs
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
WINDOW functions
SELECT
DISTINCT
UNION
ORDER BY
LIMIT and OFFSET
```

https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations

`WHERE` is evaluated before `SELECT`. Change your code to

```
SELECT 
    svc_guid,
    svc_priority,
    cast(svc_minsinqueue AS SIGNED)-(pri_svc_accept_hours * 60) AS accept_overdue,
    cast(svc_minselapsed AS SIGNED)-(pri_svc_close_hours * 60) AS closure_overdue
FROM
    svcrequest
LEFT JOIN 
    priorities
ON 
    pri_id=svc_priority
WHERE
    cast(svc_minsinqueue AS SIGNED)-(pri_svc_accept_hours * 60) > 0 OR
    cast(svc_minselapsed AS SIGNED)-(pri_svc_close_hours * 60) > 0
ORDER BY 
    accept_overdue DESC;
```

Comment: SQL does not have an "order of operation".  SQL statements *describe* the result set being produced.  There is an ordering for scoping identifiers during the compilation phase, but this answer is misleading.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use column name alias  in where clause
the where clause is  evaluated  before the select clause so the db engine can't know this column alias 
for build a correct query  you must copy the related  column code

```
SELECT 
    svc_guid,
    svc_priority,
    cast(svc_minsinqueue AS SIGNED)-(pri_svc_accept_hours * 60) AS accept_overdue,
    cast(svc_minselapsed AS SIGNED)-(pri_svc_close_hours * 60) AS closure_overdue
FROM
    svcrequest
LEFT JOIN 
    priorities
ON 
    pri_id=svc_priority
WHERE
    cast(svc_minsinqueue AS SIGNED)-(pri_svc_accept_hours * 60)  > 0 OR
    cast(svc_minselapsed AS SIGNED)-(pri_svc_close_hours * 60) > 0
ORDER BY 
accept_overdue DESC;
```

as you can see  the ORDER BY clause do the fact is evaluated  as  last .. can use the column alias

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT 
    svc_guid,
    svc_priority,
    cast(svc_minsinqueue AS SIGNED)-(pri_svc_accept_hours * 60) AS accept_overdue,
    cast(svc_minselapsed AS SIGNED)-(pri_svc_close_hours * 60) AS closure_overdue
FROM
    svcrequest
LEFT JOIN 
    priorities
ON 
    pri_id=svc_priority
WHERE
    cast(svc_minsinqueue AS SIGNED)-(pri_svc_accept_hours * 60)  > 0 OR
    cast(svc_minselapsed AS SIGNED)-(pri_svc_close_hours * 60) > 0
ORDER BY 
    3 DESC;
```

Comment: I've already accepted an answer but you'd get a +1 from me if this included a brief explanation of why this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these aliased columns in a `HAVING` clause instead of `WHERE`:

```
HAVING
    accept_overdue > 0 OR
    closure_overdue > 0
ORDER BY 
   accept_overdue DESC
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Doesn't this require GROUP BY?

Comment: No it does not require GROUP BY and it should work. The difference is that it is processed after the select statement.

Answer (score -1):

Though both tables have different column names it is recommended to specify them adding alias, this way:

:
FROM
    svcrequest as r
LEFT JOIN 
    priorities as p
ON 
:

Then, before each column you should now add these alias. 
E.g.

SELECT 
    p.svc_guid,

Of course if **svc_guid** belongs to **priorities** table

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I understand this is good practice but this wasn't the issue and this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error OP is having.